# Displaying Logging Information in View Model

Tags: c#, .net, logging, mvvm, log4net

After I log something in my program, I stored the Logging information in a public field called LogItems in the class CustomLogger.

EDIT: My CustomLogger class now implements IMyLogger

```
public class CustomLogger : IMyLogger
{

// LogItems are stored in this field. Assume that it is not Null.
public ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>

public CustomLogger()
{
}

// Other methods that populate the LogItems field

}
```

IMyLogger is the following:

```
public interface IMyLogger : ILoggerFacade
{
    ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the LogItems object from the CustomLogger class? I would need the LogItems in order to display it in my viewModel. My ViewModel class is the following:

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class LoggerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems { get; set; }
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggerViewModel));

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LoggerViewModel(CustomLogger cLogger)
    {
    // Can anyone tell me why I cannot call LogItems from cLogger here? An activation error is being thrown here.
        LogItems = cLogger.LogItems;
    }
}
```

After running the code, I get an activation error when trying to get instance of type LoggerView, key "".

If I change the LoggerViewModel constructor to

```
    public LoggerViewModel()
    {       
    }
```

No error is thrown but nothing is displayed in my view model.

How would I be able to display logging information in my view model?

Comment: I did not use an IOC.
If I change the type to the interface, ILoggerFacade, then I will have no access to LogItems in the CustomLogger class, right?

Comment: Hi, using IoC can be handy, and you should cosider using it. You can change the type to interface and you will have the access. That it can look: publc interface ILoggerFacade { ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems {get;set;} }

Comment: @Jarek, can you give further details about what you mean by "changing the type to interface"? The interface ILoggerFacade is from the Microsoft Prism Library so it cannot be modified.

Comment: interface IMyLogger : ILoggerFacade { ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems {get;set;} }

Comment: Should my CustomLogger implement the interface IMyLogger?

Comment: Yes, you should basically replace ILoggerFacade with IMyLogger.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your LoggerViewModel? Do you use any IoC framework or you create the instance yourself?

It looks like you are trying to use ViewModelLocator in LoggerView.xaml. Since you put an argument to your constructor you need to resolve it. You have 2 options:

1. If you use IoC like SimpleIoC from MVVM light, register CustomLogger first like this.
   `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CustomLogger>();`
2. Create your LoggerViewModel in the code and then assign DataContext to LoggerView manually.
   `LoggerViewModel vm = new LoggerViewModel(new CustomLogger());
   this.loggerView.DataContext = vm;`

I hope this helps.

=========================================================================
More details with regards to solution 1.
If you decide to use SimpleIoC then:

1. You need to register your CustomLogger and LoggerViewModel in constructor of ViewModelLocator

   `SimpleIoc.Default.Register< CustomLogger>();
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register< LoggerViewModel>();`

LoggerViewModel constructor should have constructor with CustomLogger argument, IoC will take of this.

2. In ViewModelLocator you should expose a property

   `public LoggerViewModel LoggerViewModel
   {
       get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance< LoggerViewModel>(); }
   }`

   3. In LoggerView.xaml you should have DataContext of our View set to ViewModelLocator with path LoggerViewModel

   `< UserControls ....
   DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=LoggerViewModel}">`

Comment: I create the instance myself. Where would I write 

LoggerViewModel vm = new LoggerViewModel(new CustomLogger());
this.loggerView.DataContext = vm;

In the CustomLogger or in the LoggerViewModel?

Comment: Hi, you should not do it in the ViewModel - ViewModel cannot refer View directly. I would put this code in the LoggerView.xaml in the Initialization method.          this.DataContext = new LoggerViewModel(new CustomLogger());

Comment: If I choose to use the former option, do I register the CustomLogger in the LoggerView constructor? Would I need to remove the parameter LoggerViewModel in the constructor?

Comment: Very unclear. What former option are you refering to?

Comment: I am referring to

1. If you use IoC like SimpleIoC from MVVM light, register CustomLogger first like this. SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CustomLogger>();